# wordpress webpack javascript function not found from Theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

my `alertHi.js` will be loaded but i cant use it from the Theme.

##### JS-Source alertHi.js:

this ( `inc/Components/Darkmode/src/alertHi.js` )
will be executed when i load the page:

```js
function alertHi(){ alert('hi') }
alertHi();
console.log('is loaded');
```

[image: is defined when loading]

But

##### html-Source

```html
<a onclick="alertHi()">☀️</a>
```

creates this error:

##### Error: alertHi is not defined

but if i call the function `alertHi()` from the page i get Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: alertHi is not defined
    onclick http://localhost/wordpress/:1
```

Any idea?

##### JS-Min-Source dist/alertHi.min.js:

webback has generated `dist/alertHi.min.js`

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The require scope
/******/    var __webpack_require__ = {};
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
// This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it need to be isolated against other entry modules.
(() => {
/*!*************************************************!*\
  !*** ./inc/Components/Darkmode/src/alertHi.js ***!
  \*************************************************/
function alertHi() {
  alert('alertHi says hello :)');
}
alertHi();
console.log('script loaded');
})();

// This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it need to be in strict mode.
(() => {
"use strict";
/*!***************************************************!*\
  !*** ./inc/Components/Darkmode/src/alertHi.scss ***!
  \***************************************************/
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin

})();

/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=alertHi.min.js.map
```

##### was reading before:

- [Cannot call javascript function in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183247/cannot-call-javascript-function-in-wordpress)
- [Hiding Javascript Function File from WordPress Theme Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69356030/hiding-javascript-function-file-from-wordpress-theme-footer)

and tried a tip read here [Cannot call javascript function in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183247/cannot-call-javascript-function-in-wordpress)

but get the error jQuery is not defined

will also not be found if i using

```js
(function($) {
    function alertHi(){
       alert('hi')
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: _"webback has generated dist/darkmode.min.js"_ - and where does that actually get embedded now - in the head, or the footer?

Comment: `<a onclick="alertHi()">☀️</a>` - why would something this "ugly" be in your theme file to begin with; why is the click handler not added _via_ JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: @CBroe its not embedded in the head and not in the footer. is it not  embedded then? maybe this is the reason. wondering that i get the alert message when i load the page but this error (not defined) if i press the link.

Comment: Well if it wasn't included at all, you could hardly get the alert. Maybe it gets combined into one single JS resource, together with the code from other files ...?

Comment: @CBroe i don't know why the click i added like so. is it wrong? it works if i put the js-Souce into the page `single.php`

Comment: Well it is very "old-school", to add event handlers via HTML attributes. This should rather be done using `addEventListener` in native JavaScript, or using `.on()` in jQuery.

Comment: yes its combined i think. by webpack

Comment: @CBroe i get same error (`ReferenceError: is not defined `)  if i use `addEventListener`

Answer (score 2):

webpack by default wraps all of the bundle internally, you can't access it externally unless explicitly setting it in the webpack config as a library.
you can also hack it out and add `window.alertHi = alertHi` in your js code but this is not recommended.

please refer to webpack's configuration API and set your bundle output to be a library. (preferably - UMD/commonjs library)

Comment: but it runs when page loaded. It just can't be executed later from the page. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

inspired by answers below this question ( [Define global variable with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37656592/2891692) ) and this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35825562/2891692 i found a solution:

Use the global window object

```js
window.alertHi = function (){ alert('hi') }
```

Comment: this is more of a hack rather than the right solution. the right solution would be to configure webpack to output your bundle as a library and then it will already define it on your window object to use as you wish. please take a look - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary